# Not able to find equivalent classes for LINQ to sql in Entity framework

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-5

I am trying to convert a method which is used to build a where condition and this is based on LINQ to sql. When i trying to convert this method to support entity framework am not able to find the equivalent classes in Entity framework.

Here are some places where i have challenges.

```
 switch (dataMember.Member.MemberType) 
    {
        case MemberTypes.Field: memberExp = Expression.Field(param, (FieldInfo)dataMember.Member); break;
    }
```

here the `datamember` is the `System.Data.linq.MetaDataMember` class
I have EdmProperty class which represents `dataMember` in the above code. How can i get `System.Reflection.MemberType` from EdmProperty?